# Replace pandas column with conditon

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas df where I need to replace column name with value from row based on condition only for some columns.

```
 parameter.1.value| parameter.1.name |  parameter.2.value |parameter.2.name ....
 1                | abc              |   4                |xyz
 2                | abc              |   3                |xyz
 3                | abc              |   6                |xyz
```

**Goal**

```
 abc  |  xyz 
 1    |   4              
 2    |   3                
 3    |   6
```

Note:

There are other columns as well in df, also the number and location of the parameter value-name columns pair are not always same in each df

Another example with 3 pairs

```
parameter.1.value| parameter.1.name |  parameter.2.value |parameter.2.name|  parameter.3.value |parameter.3.name  .... 

 1               | abc              |   4                |xyz           |2 | ttt
 2               | abc              |   3                |xyz           |8 | ttt
 3               | abc              |   6                |xyz           |7 | ttt
```

Comment: There are strings columns with same values?

Comment: string column values are all same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all even columns by positions and then set new columns names by odd values in first row of DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, ::2]
df1.columns = df.iloc[0, 1::2]
print (df1)
0  abc  xyz
0    1    4
1    2    3
2    3    6
```

EDIT: If need select by names:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='parameter.value1')
df1.columns = df.filter(like='parameter.name1').iloc[0]
print (df1)
0  abc  xyz
0    1    4
1    2    3
2    3    6
```

EDIT1: If is possible select `value` and `name` columns use:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='value')
df1.columns = df.filter(like='name').iloc[0]
```

Comment: the thing is that there are other columns as well in df, also the number and location of the parameter value- name columns are not always same

Comment: @alex3465 - hmmm, so please change data sample. How is possible select columns, if no position possible?

Comment: the second solution works but I want to automate this for example in each df the parameter name-value pair are not same and df might have other column as well, only do this replacing where we have parameter name-value pairs

Comment: @alex3465 - `for example in each df the parameter-value pair are not same` can you post some examples?

Comment: in given example its 2, parameter 1  and 2, sometime df have these pairs 3 ,4, or 5 ,

Comment: @alex3465 - Sorry, I need examples of colums names, how looks strings exactly. From `df have these pairs 3 ,4, or 5 ` not understand how looks.

Comment: @alex3465 - can you check `EDIT1` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241680/discussion-between-alex3465-and-jezrael).